# Saving Edits in ArcMap automatically smooths line feature?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, editing

Using ArcMap 10.3.1: I'm having an issue with automatic smoothing of line features after editing vertices of line features and clicking 'Save Edits'.

I start my editing session, click on a line feature, click on a vertex, delete that vertex using the Edit Vertices toolbar, click 'Save Edits', and my line feature becomes very generalized/smooth instead of just removing that vertex. I'm having the same problem when adding a vertex.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: Is your line a curve? How are you removing the vertex?

Comment: Yes, line is a curve. I'm using the Delete Vertex tool within the Edit Vertices toolbar so I turn the Delete Vertex tool on, click on the vertex which then deletes that vertex. Then I click "Save Edits" from the Editor toolbar and instead of just removing that vertex, my entire curve geometry changes into a very generalized curve.

Comment: Which spatial reference are you using?

Comment: Generalise and smooth are two opposite things.

Comment: Is it perchance a shapefile that you're editing? Shapefiles do not support curve geometries and automatically stroke the curves on save. If not have a read of http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//003n00000005000000 (Ctrl + F and look for *Feature tolerances*)

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include screenshots before and after to help illustrate what is happening?